# Where to find / browse cookies in app data folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cookiemanager

I have my app ("*myapp*") with following example package signature: `com.example.mycorp.myapp`

I browsed via `adb shell` the app folder /data/data/com.example.mycorp.myapp/ to find any cookies - in vain.

Since I have WebView objects showing external links (html) and Google Login as an example, there should be some cookies created (at least iOS colleagues have there cookies on the same app for iOS).

**So where are can I find any cookies regarding my own app?**

Comment: You can debug your WebViews with the Chrome Devtools. With USB-Debugging enabled, launch your application and open chrome://inspect. Your app should be listed there and a link to inspect the WebView.https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically by means of [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html):

Memeber variable

```
private CookieManager cookieManager = null;
```

In a onCreate() or another constructor

```
cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

A checkCookies() Method which can be triggered frequently

```
List<HttpCokie> cookies = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Now, iterate through `cookies` and print them out.

Comment: Will it be a device wide cookie store ?  I mean will the last line provide only the cookies belonging to the calling application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the cookie value you can use this:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://the.url.com")
```

More help will be provided here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getCookie(java.lang.String)